# If $f(f(x)) = f(x^2)$, then must there be some constant $c$ such that $f(x)=c$ for all values of $x$ in the domain of $f$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Here is a problem from Rusczyk-Crawford's Art of Problems Solving: Intermediate Algebra textbook (Chapter 2 Review, problem 2.30).

> If $f(f(x)) = f(x^2)$, then must there be some constant $c$ such that $f(x)=c$ for all values of $x$ in the domain of $f$?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: This seems like a pretty interesting problem. However, what have you done to try to solve it?

Comment: Let the domain be $\{0,1\}$ and let $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$.

Comment: And what are your instincts: Do you think it's true, or false? Have you tried looking for counterexamples?

Comment: I think that the assumption that $f$ must be continuous might be missing.

Comment: If $f$ is invertible, we obtain that $f(x)=x^2$ (which means that the domain of $f$ is contained in $[0,\infty)$ or in $(-\infty,0]$).

Comment: I think I've found a counterexample: what if $f(x)=x^2$, then $f(f(x))=x^4$ and $f(x^2)=X^4$ as well; however, f(x) does not equal a constant for all values of x. Is this a valid counter-example?

Comment: It is valid, unless there are conditions on $f$ that were left out of the post. Write an answer!

Comment: Richarddedekind beat me to it, luckily I was able to solve it on my own before reading his answer (as Noble Mushtak and pjs36 encouraged me to do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is false.

If $f(x)=x^2$ then obviously $f(f(x))=f(x^2)$ but $\nexists \ c\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=c \ \ \ \forall x\in D(x)$, where $D(x)$ is the domain of $f$.

Comment: Nice observation.